# how to get the uibutton state value in test.m file

Tags: ios, unit-testing, ios7, ios5

In .m file i have methods like

```
-(void) textdata
{
    long i = search.text.length; 
    if (i > 0) {
        searchButton.enabled = YES;        
    }
    else
    {
        searchButton.enabled = NO;
    }
    [self buttonstate];
}

-(int) buttonstate 
{
    if ([searchButton isEnabled]) {
        j = 1;
    }
    else
       j = 0;

    NSLog(@" j value is %d",j);
    return j;
}

- (void) textFieldDidChange 
{
    [self textdata];
    NSLog(@"test data is %@",search.text);
}
```

And in the `tests.m` file i have test like

```
-(void) testwithoutData 
{
    myapiViewController  *apiViw = [[myapiViewController alloc]init];
    [apiViw textdata];

    int kn  = [apiViw buttonstate];
    NSLog(@"the value is %ld",(long)kn);
}
```

Comment: In your case its actually pointing to nil that's why you are getting j=0. This is because it create a new reference to the view controller. I think you have to add these methods in tests.m file and pass value manually.

Comment: Please elaborate it for me sir

Answer (score 0):

You have to do alloc init because due to this instance variable getting nil. Try this -

In ViewController.m -

```
-(int) buttonstate {

long i = self.searchTxt.text.length;

if (i > 0) {
    self.searchBtn.enabled = YES;
}
else
{
    self.searchBtn.enabled = NO;
}

if ([self.searchBtn isEnabled]) {
    j = 1;
}
else    
j = 0;


NSLog(@" j value is %d",j);

return j;
}
```

In ViewControllerTests.m -

```
- (void)testExample {
    // This is an example of a functional test case.
    XCTAssert(YES, @"Pass");
    self.vcToTest.searchTxt = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    self.vcToTest.searchBtn = [[UIButton alloc] init];

    self.vcToTest.searchTxt.text = @"test";
    int kn  = [self.vcToTest buttonstate];    
    NSLog(@"the value is %ld",(long)kn);
}
```

Check the attached screenshot output -
[image]

Comment: sir i am having UItextField and UiButton when user taps and textField contains data then button will enable i want a test case in test case i will be giving searchtextField.text = @"xxx" then check j = 1, then test case buttonenabled will pass by XCTAssertEqual ( j,1 ) i am trying that thing sir.

Comment: sir i have one doubt sir while loading view if i don't call method textData if i put seachtextField.text = @"xxxxx" then the button is not enabled if i call the method then button is enabled why? sir why it was not able to recognize it

Comment: check my updated code. see since you are calling method of viewcontroller in your test file. so when you pass data for searchtextField from tests.m actually in viewcontroller its getting nil. so to avoid this you have to do alloc init.

Comment: sir it is working for if i put the searchtext.text = @"" then it is not working sir

Comment: For searchtext.text=@"" you will get j=0. Because it will not satisfy i>0 condition. What problem you are facing?

Comment: sir i have methods - (textData) , -(buttonState), if i run the program with textData in ViewDidLoad then the button is enabled it shoud not suppose to enable the button sir

Comment: Thanks Uttam, Let me restate my problem. I have a textfield and a button. The button should be enabled when there is text present in the textfield and be disabled when there is no text. I have implemented all the delegate methods properly and everything is working fine when I RUN the application.

Comment: Thanks Uttam, Let me restate my problem. I have a textfield and a button. The button should be enabled when there is text present in the textfield and be disabled when there is no text. I have implemented all the delegate methods properly and everything is working fine when I RUN the application. Now I am a writing a simple unit test for the above scenario. I am using the uitextfield.text = @"abc" to set the text. This call is not invoking any delegate methods nor observer/notifications are working.